# Restoring mysql database gives errors

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to restore a database using the following code from http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/php-script-to-import-mysql-database
But i am receiving "Error: Query was empty"
Where am i going wrong?

P.s. importing the sql file from phpmyadmin serves the purpose but doesnt work using this.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$filename = 'DB_Backups/db-backup-08-04-14-08-39-16.sql';
$templine = '';
$lines = file($filename); //Read entire file
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '') //Skip all comments
        $templine.=$line;
    if(substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';'){
        mysql_query($templine) or print('Error: '.mysql_error().'<br>');
    $templine = '';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check what is inside you $templine, because it seems that you are trying to execute  a empty query.

Comment: The content of **db-backup-08-04-14-08-39-16.sql** would help.

Comment: At a glance at the code I can see that the templine becomes empty but thats the code given in the link above.

Comment: Why not use some standard utility, such as 'phpmyadmin'? just curious

Comment: Its because I want this important utility to be a part of the application I am developing

Comment: `if(substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')` - this won't exclude empty lines or lines with only spaces in them, that's one. Secondly, while this is one way to restore, it's by far not the best way, since you have to indeed to SQL validation yourself before passing it to `mysql_query`. A much easier way would be to `system()` execution of MySQL client itself.

Comment: @Carl Markham, its a preety large file. Should I post it? But I can say that if I import that sql file through phpmyadmin it gets executed.

Comment: @favoretti, I have managed the sql validation part but dont know how to resolve the part you mentioned.

Comment: Well, if you get the errors on queries, then you didn't manage SQL validation just yet :)

Comment: in that case i would appreciate some help. :)

Comment: Well, printing the query (or logging it) in case of error would be a good start :)

Comment: i used
 
     echo $templine;

just before the query line and commented the query. Nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight improvement and it works :) @ favoretti thank you for the hint.

```
<?php
// Name of the file
$filename = 'DB_Backups/'.$name;


// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    // Skip it if it's a comment
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
        continue;

    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;
    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
    {
    // Perform the query
    mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, this part of code doesn't *skip* comments, it literally adds them to your `$templine`:

```
    if(substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '') //Skip all comments
        $templine.=$line;
```

Secondly, here you try to execute query with `$templine` assigned above (if it ever was assigned, or otherwise `''`), where you actually want to execute query with `$line`:

```
    if(substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';'){
        mysql_query($templine) or print('Error: '.mysql_error().'<br>');
```

So, basically this should work somewhat better:

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '') //Skip all comments
        continue;
    if(substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';'){
        mysql_query(trim($line)) or print('Error: '.mysql_error().'in ' . $line . '<br>');
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see the queries getting executed but with errors.
"Error: Table 'duplicate.courses' doesn't exist"
it gives errors for each table in the file.
plus it also tells me that 
"Error: You have an error in your sql syntax check manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 1

Comment: Relate back to my comment about SQL parsing.. Dumps are not line by line, they are multi-line as well. Believe me, you're much better off executing SQL client in the background.

Comment: I am not much familiar of using the client. Can you show me how to do it?