# XAMPP and importing .sql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have an sql file that contains 1.74+ Million records, this is not your average database import.

I lifted the upload minimum to 128MB from the 8MB limit as well as the memory limit to 1GB, should it need it. Only 251 of the records ever get processed before I get an out of memory error on a machine that has 1GB RAM at its disposal, this makes no sense at all. Despite the claims to be importing records, the web host like my local host, stalls. The uncompressed file is 230MB, compressed its 36MB.

I tried to write a routine for my local server and I find that I am not able to access or insert data, I get an Access denied error (42000/1044) and when I look it up, its about access and needing root privis...

Any suggestions on how to get either the file split properly or imported via a script because PHPMyAdmin has I am afraid to say, lost the plot. Its not helping much and much of the documentation assumes you have physical access to systems, so I can't find anything helpful in the doc's, I keep on going around in circles... HELP!

Comment: Just upload it using the command line.

Comment: The routine has to be on your remote server to work, not local. If you cannot upload any scripts on the remote server, your choice is limited to phpmyadmin and splitting the Statements in the SQL file to various files. You cannot just arbitrarily split the file otherwise the SQL will fail.

Comment: I have illustrated on the file splitting issue in my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a good idea to use a browser based UI for large records.

1) If it is an SQL file try using mysql command line

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword db_name < file.sql
```

2) If it is a CSV file use mysqlimport, the table name should match the filename (without extension), and you can define the delimiters and whether to ignore 1st row (if first row is headers).

3) Or try out [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), but I found command-line works best, even on Windows.

4) If your choice is only the installed phpmyadmin and you cannot upload any scripts such as Adminer to the remote server, then one of the limited choice you are left is to split SQL file/queries and process them. An example of correct and wrong splitting is given below:

bigfile.sql

```
Insert into tablex values ('A','AA'),
('B','BB'),('C','CC'),('D','DD');
```

Splits to

file1.sql

```
Insert into tablex values ('A','AA'), ('B','BB');
```

files2.sql

```
Insert into tablex values ('C','CC'), ('D','DD');
```

You should NOT split it like below... it will fail...

file1.sql

```
Insert into tablex values ('A','AA'),
```

files2.sql

```
('B','BB'), ('C','CC'), ('D','DD');
```

Comment: on my local PC that would be fine, this is a web host and I have no access to SQL directly, so this I know will not work for my situation, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok, then try https://www.adminer.org/
It seems to be able to handle large files, only limit is the configuration limits placed by you webhost. If you can upload the gz file, I think that limit can be overcome.

Comment: Adminer has way less bloat than phpmyadmin, if you like it, give the developer a star on github :)

Comment: I have spent 4 hours yesterday uploading the same 36 MB .sql.zip (as requested format) to be told repeatedly to re-upload the same 36MB compressed file and it eventually crashed after the 13th or 14th upload and it only inserted 1,982 records out of 1.7 Odd million records. I have tried a file splitting tool but its truncating and breaking the records.

Comment: Do you not have ssh access? If you do then you can probably use the command line on the host... you just need to specify the host address with `-h` and possibly the port.

Comment: @Mark, how about ftp / sftp access, is it provided? Or if the site is a wordpress one are you able to install a plugin?

Comment: I ftp'd the file, I don't use ssh. In the meantime it has been worked out that the fault lies with the host, I used my regular host and it uploaded and processed fine. The other host, I basically lambasted them for lax security on their servers. Long story short, their fault not mine and thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found an answer about this in SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123863/restoring-mysql-database-gives-errors)). <strike>I will try to search it again to provide its URL.</strike> This is the code i used to accomplish the same task.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000M');


// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
$filename = 'filename.sql';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // Skip it if it's a comment
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '') {
        continue;
    }

    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;
    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
        // Perform the query
        mysqli_query($connection, $templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysqli_error($connection) . '<br /><br />');
        // Reset temp variable to empty
        $templine = '';
    }
}
echo "Tables imported successfully";
```

Comment: I have attempted a similar approach and this is what is giving me an error, nothing is updating or inserting locally or remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the support, the matter has been resolved. Like the routine, similar to mine that was failing, not because of code but the hosts SQL servers.